# Accessing the text value of custom column with NetSuite SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am working with NetSuite's server-side SuiteScript and need to access the display value of several custom Transaction Column Fields. The fields in question are each set up as type "List/Record" and are associated with existing Custom Lists.

Working in the NetSuite Script Debugger, I have inspected the values returned from `nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', orderInternalId)`. Looking at the Items in the resulting object (e.g. `obj.sublists.item.line 1`) I see that some of these List/Record custom fields provide both a number (the ID of the selected List entry) and a string (the displayed text value of the List entry), but other custom fields do not.

For example, I have two custom fields with IDs `custcol1` and `custcol2`. These are both of type "List/Record". When the sales order is loaded, nlapiLoadRecord provides the fields "custcol1" (number) and "custcol1_display" (string) for `custcol1`, but only "custcol2" (number) for `custcol2`. I do not see any difference in the settings for these two custom fields, so it is unclear why one provides the string and the other does not.

I need to retrieve the string values for both fields. Is there a setting change I need to make so `custcol2` will automatically return a "custcol2_display" value? Or is there another API call I can use to take the number value from "custcol2" and look up the associated string value in the underlying Custom List?

Comment: Have you tried calling getLineItemValue / getLineItemText on the fields? If so, what is returned? I like the debugger, but I find that sometimes a `nlapiLogExecution('debug','getLineItemValue returned: ",value);` is alot more effective.

Comment: The API nlobjRecord.getLineItemText is not supported in user-event sublist.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `record.getLineItemText('item', 'custcol2', linenum)`

For debugging, I tend to use Firebug - it's a lot more effective than the NS debugger and quicker than logging statements for just testing things out.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed this is two years old, but I think you can put columnname.id to get the data value. It works for standard columns but not sure about custom ones.

One thing I have learned to use is the NetSuite debugger, I don't use it like a standard debugger but rather like the javascript console. Just paste in some code into the box and then debug it, it is great for seeing what the dang property values are and the data in them which seems to be a crapshoot in NetSuite.

Comment: One thing that is particularly vexing about the "debugger" is how it seems to get wiped out by everything/anything. For instance, you have some code pasted in that affects Customer records, if you look at a known-to-be-affected Customer you will be greeted with the "someone else has logged in" message.

Somehow this even persists across browsers not just tabs. Do yourself a favor and keep a text editor handy for clipboard duties.